# android simple UTF-8 Error ..Don't know How to solve

Tags: android, eclipse, logcat, android-logcat

while creating I facing this error :
for solution where to change I did n't please guide me..

```
 -version-name
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        inserts android:versionName in to manifest.
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]    --custom-package
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        generates R.java into a different package.
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]    --auto-add-overlay
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        Automatically add resources that are only in overlays.
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]    --rename-manifest-package
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        Rewrite the manifest so that its package name is the package name
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        given here.  Relative class names (for example .Foo) will be
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        changed to absolute names with the old package so that the code
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        does not need to change.
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]    --rename-instrumentation-target-package
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        Rewrite the manifest so that all of its instrumentation
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        components target the given package.  Useful when used in
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        conjunction with --rename-manifest-package to fix tests against
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        a package that has been renamed.
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]    --product
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        Specifies which variant to choose for strings that have
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        product variants
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]    --utf16
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        changes default encoding for resources to UTF-16.  Only useful when API
[2012-03-30 11:49:31 - Helloworld]        level is set to 7 or higher where the default encoding is UTF-8.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing this type of error .
Please run your program into the android version 2.3. something or above ..
You cann't face this error again.

Just read your last two **logcate** utf-16 so..do it if you are getting other error.
please post your logcat here agian with that error..

for changing it just do it like:

```
project -> right click -> properties ->Android ->default 2.2 is selected in your case.
or any low version.
```

chose the android 2.3. or above and run program again.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Know Exactly that this is creating problem but you can give a try to this.

> Go to Project in eclipse -> Right Click -> Properties -> Resources ->
>   Under Text File Encoding - Select Other -> Select UTF -16 from Drop-
>   Down -> Apply and OK

Build and Clean the Project.

Comment: i didn't find this  **Under Text File Encoding - Select** ..
can you please guide me for that...

Comment: @fullError Dont you have "Text File Encodig -  on the Right side when you selecet Resource"

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to validate a document because on line 142 it contained one or more bytes that cannot be interpreted as utf-8 (in other words, the bytes found are not valid values in the specified character encoding). Please check both the content of the file and the character encoding indication.

The error was:

> utf8 "\xA9" does not map to Unicode

In order to fix this, remove characters like **©** and any Chinese characters.